# Array is Undefined in Foreach // Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Tags: php

> Notice: Undefined variable: parts3
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

There is nothing wrong with the first two array; `$parts` and `$parts2`. But when it comes to `$parts3` it is undefined to the foreach.

```
$round[0]=5;
$round[1]=4;
$round[2]=6;
$round[3]=2;

$slice=3;
$count=0;
$partscount=0;
$parts=explode( ',', $round ) ;
$store; 
$parts2;
$parts3; 

foreach($parts as $index => $value):        

    if($value>$slice) {
        $store[$count]=$slice;              
        $parts2[$partscount]=$value-$slice;
        $partscount++;
        $count++;
    } else {
        switch ($value){
            case 1:
                $store[$count]=1;
                $count++;
                break;
            case 2:
                $store[$count]=2;
                $count++;
                break;
        }
    }    

endforeach;


foreach($parts as $index => $value):        

    if($value>$slice){
        $store[$count]=$slice;          
        $count++;
        $partscount++;
        $parts3[$partscount]=$value-$slice;
    } else {
        switch ($value){
            case 1:
                $store[$count]=1;
                $count++;
                break;
            case 2:
                $store[$count]=2;
                $count++;
                break;  
        }
    }
    
endforeach;

foreach($parts3 as $index => $value):       

    $cut=$value;
    if($value>$slice){
        $store[$count]=$slice;          
        $count++;   
        $partscount++;
        $parts4[$partscount]=$value-$slice;
    } else {
        switch ($value){
            case 1:
                $store[$count]=1;
                $count++;
                break;
            case 2:
                $store[$count]=2;
                $count++;
                break;
        }
    }

endforeach;
```

Comment: `explode()` takes a `string` as argument, `$round` is an `array`

Comment: `$parts3` is `null`. You change `$parts3 = array();` on line 12. `$parts` and `$parts2` are no problem because `explode()` first `foreach` changed them to `array`. But, `explode()` for `String`, not `Array`

Answer (score 0):

`explode()` takes a `string` as argument and `$round` is an `array`, you may want to use:

```
$round[]=5;
$round[]=4;
$round[]=6;
$round[]=2;

$slice=3;
$count=0;
$partscount=0;

$store;
$parts2;
$parts3;
foreach($round as $index => $value)
{
    if ($value > $slice) {
        $store[$count] = $slice;
        $parts2[$partscount] = $value - $slice;
        $partscount++;
        $count++;
    } else {

        switch ($value) {
            case 1:
                $store[$count] = 1;
                $count++;
                break;
            case 2:
                $store[$count] = 2;
                $count++;
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Note: I don't check all your code because I don't understand what you're doing, but the error is gone and `print_r($store)` outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 2
)
```

Answer (score 0):

parts3 never fill, you have an error in

foreach(**$parts2 as $values**):

```
if(**$value>$slice**){
```